# PDO as constructor argument

Tags: php, php-7

I have the following class:

```
class UserRepository {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->$conn = $conn;
    }

    //Methods omitted

}
```

I use the following to create a UserRepository object:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$userRepository = new UserRepository($conn);
```

I'm getting the following error in the constructor of the UserRepository:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor uses the variable as dynamic attribute-name. Therefore it tries to convert it to a string. `$this->{$conn} = $conn` vs. `$this->conn = $conn`.

```
    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
```